# Firing event in Parallel.ForEach()

Tags: c#, .net, events, parallel.foreach

I'm using the following code to speed up retrieving data from a COM Object:

```
        const string status = "Getting node displacements...";
        int count;
        int totalCount;
        IEnumerable<ILoadCase> loadCases;
        ConcurrentBag<NodeDisplacements> nodeDisplacements;

        // Check if results are even available
        if (!this.HasResults)
            return null;

        // Get node displacements
        nodeDisplacements = new ConcurrentBag<NodeDisplacements>();
        loadCases = this.LoadCases.Cast<ILoadCase>().Union(this.LoadCombinations.Cast<ILoadCase>()).Where(lc => lc.ID >= StartLoadCase && lc.ID <= EndLoadCase);
        count = 0;
        totalCount = this.Nodes.Count * loadCases.Count();
        Parallel.ForEach(this.Nodes, (node) => {
            Parallel.ForEach(loadCases, (loadCase) => {
                nodeDisplacements.Add(this.GetNodeDisplacements(node, loadCase));
                this.OnModelBuildStatusUpdate(new ModelBuildStatusUpdateEventArgs(status, Interlocked.Increment(ref count), totalCount));   
            });
        });
```

At the moment I am testing this via a command prompt, following progress through an event fired in `this.OnModelBuildStatusUpdate(...)`.

Because of the parallel loops, the event is fired multiple times. To try to avoid the command prompt being flooded with `"Getting node displacements..."` messages I tried this:

```
    private static string previouStatusMessage;

    static void model_ModelBuildStatusUpdate(StaadModel sender, ModelBuildStatusUpdateEventArgs e)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(previouStatusMessage) || !previouStatusMessage.Equals(e.StatusMessage))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.StatusMessage);
                previouStatusMessage = e.StatusMessage;
            }

            Console.Write("\r{0:0.00%}", e.ElementsProcessed / (double)e.TotalElementsToProcess);
        }
```

To only display the first status message, but at the moment it displays multiple times (once for each outer loop thread?). I imaging I need to lock something here, but I can't figure out what.

I'd appreciate it if somebody could show me how to implement the event raising properly for this.

Comment: What is this status message you only want to display once? Can you not move that part outside the loop since it sounds like it doesn't actually depend on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your handler isn't thread safe. Try this:

```
private static string previouStatusMessage;
private static object lockObject = new object();

static void model_ModelBuildStatusUpdate(StaadModel sender, ModelBuildStatusUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        lock (lockObject)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(previouStatusMessage) || !previouStatusMessage.Equals(e.StatusMessage))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.StatusMessage);
                previouStatusMessage = e.StatusMessage;
            }
        }
        Console.Write("\r{0:0.00%}", e.ElementsProcessed / (double)e.TotalElementsToProcess);
    }
```

Comment: @yu_ominae Yes that did the trick but keep in mind that all threads will be synchronized at that `lock`. You won't have much benefit of multithreading using this sample code. Hopefully your real code does much more complex operations so that this is a real solution. You can try using something lockless but that's more complex and I think in the case of the sample code it won't give you a raise over that `lock`.

Comment: @Verarind Sorry, I don't get what you mean? Even with the lock this runs about ten times faster than without the parallel loop (I remove the inner one, because there was no point in it). I just want to launch multiple queries at the COM object to retrieve data faster as getting the data is the bottle neck in what I'm trying to do.

Comment: COM objects don't handle parallelism well. You're usually required to call them from an `STAThread` only.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I guess that's all down to the internals of the COM object? In this case I'm not getting any problems, all data seems to be correct. I'm implementing a non-parallel mode as well, so I'll switch to that if I encounter scenarios where parallelism is problematic.

Comment: @yu_ominae If you've a benefit all is fine. Use it. I don't know the amount of work of `this.GetNodeDisplacements(node, loadCase)` but if that's a fast operation all threads will be synchronized at the lock. In that case you won't have any benefit. You should keep in mind that this might is only a solution for that case but it's not a general solution for all possible cases.

Comment: Of course, I assumed that most of the work is done in `GetNodeDisplacements`. After the first call, the lock is only held for a very short time (while checking the `if` condition).

Comment: @Verarind, that's a good point, thanks. I guess it just works in this case because the COM calls are slower than the time it takes for the event to dispatch. Something to bear in mind. Thanks!